# Downloading Error With Files over 1.0GB

Tags: c#, download

Hello I'm trying to make a program that can download a file problem is when it downloads a file that is over 1GB it Crashes and breaks is there a way to make it so it can download files that are way bigger Here is the code I'm using

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient web = new WebClient();
    string listbox = listBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();

    web.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(http://example.com/file.avi), location" + "file.avi");
    web.DownloadProgressChanged += new DownloadProgressChangedEventHandler(web_DownloadProgressChanged);
    web.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadFileCompleted);
}

private void client_DownloadFileCompleted(object sender, AsyncCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    // Place for a message when the downloading has compleated
}             

void web_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    int totalbytes = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
    int kb2 = totalbytes / 1024;

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;             
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "crashes and breaks"? Is there an error message?

Comment: You need to be more specific if you want help. How does it break? Does it freeze? Does it throw an exception (and if so, what exception)?

Comment: Most likely he's getting an OutOfMemoryException. Or this: int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString()) is causing an OverflowException

Comment: Yeah Throws an error messages that is OutOfMemoryException

Comment: Do you have any other code than this? To the best of my knowlage `DownloadFileAsync` does not allocate more memory than it needs to and will only use a few MB to process the current chunk it is working on. Can you click [Copy Exception Detail to Clipboad](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/saraford/archive/2008/08/07/did-you-know-you-can-copy-the-exception-details-with-one-click-from-the-exception-assistant-276.aspx) then edit your question with the text it copied pasted in?

Comment: I think you  have to send the file in pieces.  Most servers have limits on size of !10-20MByte.  If you look at following webpage : http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/03/ip-protocol-header/ The maximum size of the IP is total Length (16 bits) * Fragment Offset (12 bits) = 2^28 = 268,435,456

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This

```
void web_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    int bytesin = int.Parse(e.BytesReceived.ToString());
    int totalbytes = int.Parse(e.TotalBytesToReceive.ToString());
    int kb1 = bytesin / 1024;
    int kb2 = totalbytes / 1024;

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;             
}
```

is causing your issue. You are converting a long to int and getting an [OverflowException](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.overflowexception(v=vs.110).aspx) once BytesReceived or TotalBytesToReceive go above int32.MaxValue.

Change the method to something like this:

```
void web_DownloadProgressChanged(object sender, DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
{
    long kb1 = e.BytesReceived / 1024;
    long kb2 = e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1024;

    toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = kb1.ToString() + "KB out of " + kb2.ToString() + "KB (" + e.ProgressPercentage.ToString() + "%)";
    progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;             
}
```

Comment: He's also getting an OutOfMemoryException.

Comment: @Ben if this code works you where not getting a OutOfMemoryException because this code does not solve that problem. Accurate information is important when asking a question.